# Representation of households and people

Tags: c#, data-structures

In C++ I could do something like this

```
class Person
{
    House * myhouse;
}

class House
{
    std::vector<Person*> members;
}
```

How can I do a similar thing in C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class Person
{
    public House MyHouse { get; set; }
}

public class House
{
    public List<Person> Members { get; private set; }

    public House()
    {
        this.Members = new List<Person>();
    }
}
```

Instead of fields here i'm using properties, in particular, automatic properties.
This is both for being cleaner, exposing a field to the outer world is usually less clean than exposing a property, and also because i can control in this way how people can access to the properties for read and for write. In this example, property Members is public for read but private for write, I initialize it in the constructor.

In C# there is not the concept of objects allocated in stack, objects are always allocated in heap.

This means classes are always reference types and a variable of type List is a reference to an object of type List, like a pointer is in C++.
For this reason you need to use the new operator to allocate it, or the default value will be null.

Of course, as you know, in C# there is the garbage collector, so you don't need to delete the object.

In C# there are also value types, basic types like int, float, double and struct are value types, and they works in a different way indeed.

Arrays and strings are still reference types (classes).

Also note that in C# class fields are initialized by default in the constructor to 0, each type you can think of will be initialized with 0, so, a pointer will be null, a float will be 0.0f, a struct will be a struct with all fields set to 0. Like a calloc in C.

There is however another totally different approach possible.
We can use the base class Collection and make the MyHouse property totally transparent and safe: we set it when we change the collection, this technique is used often.

```
    public class Person
    {
        // This field is internal, it means that all classes in the same module (in the same dll for example) can access to this field.
        // This keyword was introduced for the same reason that the "friend" keyword exists in C++.
        // We need this internal so we can modify it from House class.
        internal House house;

        public House MyHouse
        {
            get { return this.house; }
        }
    }

    public class House :
        System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Person>
    {
        // We shadow the base member, this is faster than default implementation, O(1).
        public new bool Contains(Person person)
        {
            return person != null && person.house == this;
        }

        protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
        {
            Person person = this[index];
            base.RemoveItem(index);
            person.house = null;
        }

        protected override void SetItem(int index, Person item)
        {
            if (item == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Person is null");
            if (item.house != null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Person already owned by another house");
            Person old = this[index];
            base.SetItem(index, item);
            old.house = null;
            item.house = this;
        }

        protected override void InsertItem(int index, Person item)
        {
            if (item == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Person is null");
            if (item.house != null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Person already owned by another house");
            base.InsertItem(index, item);
            item.house = this;
        }

        protected override void ClearItems()
        {
            foreach (Person person in this)
            {
                person.house = null;
            }
            base.ClearItems();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Person
{
    House myhouse;
}

class House
{
    List<Person> members = new List<Person>;
}
```

Comment: You never initialized the members, you need to initialize it with = new List<Person>(), this behave differently than C++.